# Can a trac backup be restored onto a older version, 0.11.7 -> 0.11.6

Tags: trac

I'm having to migrate a trac installation from 0.11.7 to another host who only provides 0.11.6. I am not able to update the older installation.

My question is, Is it possible to migrate? What will I lose (if anything), and What problems will I face?

I created my trac backup by following the [official instructions](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracBackup)

```
$ trac-admin /path/to/projenv hotcopy /path/to/backupdir
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall anything in the 0.11.6 -> 0.11.7 changes that would cause you problems.  To double-check, create a test Trac environment in 0.11.6, then upgrade to 0.11.7 and see if you have to run a `trac <env> upgrade` to get it working.  If you don't, I would not expect you to have any issues with the core Trac resulting from restoring a 0.11.7 environment on a 0.11.6 setup.  There might be issues with plugins, depending on what you may be using.

<sub>Disclosure: I'm one of the Trac devs</sub>

Answer (score 1):

That would require intimate knowledge of trac. Or you could read the changelog.

However, I think the trac devs would be able to answer your question best:
http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/MailingList

Post something to the user list.